# How to access configuration provider values in asp.net core startup

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-configuration

In my asp.net core 3.1 project I have setup a custom sql provider which is working great. In my Startup I want to load only the values from the SQLConfigurationProvider into a separate dictionary for use throughout my app. I can see that the configuration object contains a collection of providers as per below screenshot. However I cannot find a way to access only the SQLConfigurationProvider and get the subsequent values. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: You could loop through the providers and get the one where `provider is SQLConfigurationProvider`?

Comment: @juunas thanks but the collection of providers is not accessible from Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly use `Configuration.Providers` to get the `SQLConfigurationProvider`.

But the ConfigurationProvider's data property is protected, so we should write a extension method to get the value and set it into a directory.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Create a extension class:

```cs
public static class ConfigurationProviderExtensions
{
    public static HashSet<string> GetFullKeyNames(this IConfigurationProvider provider, string rootKey, HashSet<string> initialKeys)
    {
        foreach (var key in provider.GetChildKeys(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), rootKey))
        {
            string surrogateKey = key;
            if (rootKey != null)
            {
                surrogateKey = rootKey + ":" + key;
            }

            GetFullKeyNames(provider, surrogateKey, initialKeys);

            if (!initialKeys.Any(k => k.StartsWith(surrogateKey)))
            {
                initialKeys.Add(surrogateKey);
            }
        }

        return initialKeys;
    }
}
```

Then you could add below codes to get the provider and get the value..

```cs
// Replace the EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider to your provider 
var re =  ((ConfigurationRoot)Configuration).Providers.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.GetType() == typeof(EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider));

var directory = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var key in re.GetFullKeyNames(null, new HashSet<string>()).OrderBy(p => p))
{
    if (re.TryGet(key, out var value))
    {
        directory.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @BrandZhang Thanks for the solution I will use this. Shame it's not made simple by having the collection of providers accessible though

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is very simple. Once you build your ConfigurationRoot

```
IConfigurationRoot configRoot = config.Build();
```

What you can do is to enumerate to a `List` only the providers you want:

```
var providers = configRoot.Providers.Where(
    p => (p.GetType().Name == "AzureAppConfigurationProvider") ||
         (p.GetType().Name == "AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider")).ToList();
```

Then, recreate a new temporary ConfigurationRoot using only the selected providers:

```
var tempRoot = new ConfigurationRoot(new List<IConfigurationProvider>(providers));
```

Then, in order to get the values you can do the following:

```
tempRoot.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value)
```

This way you will get a Dictionary with the key/value pairs of the configuration.

*Note:* When you initialize a new ConfigurationRoot from the providers, the SDK triggers again the loading of the configuration which might introduce delays (especially if the configuration is retrieved from a cloud service). If you don't want something like that then you probably have to go with the solution suggested by Brando.

[image]